# mp4 Partially supported in Firefox, what are the limitations?

Tags: html, firefox, browser, html5-video

I’ve made a website related to videos and audio at the beginning of 2013 and users had to upload video both in mp4 and ogv in admin in order to be compatible with all browsers.

I see today that Firefox finally supports mp4.

On this website, caniuse http://caniuse.com/#search=mp4, it says it is « Partially supported ».

Do you know what are the limitations ? Is it safe to allow user to simply upload only in mp4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they vary, depending on os/gecko version, and between audio and video. with that said, i do not know if it is safe for users to simply upload only in .mp4, and offhand, i'd say not if you want cross-browser compatible media. there's a slew of media format converter JavaScript libraries you could implement here to convert, if you want to cover cross-browser compatibility, while just going with .mp4. and there are much more refined media libraries on the server, but i dunno what language you are using, so lets stick with frontend.
you're going to want to read the notes at the bottom of the page, after the tabular cross-browser data (sorry, not frag identifier)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: I'm using php/mysql on the server. In front, HTML5, JavaScript / jQuery). I use a mutualized server so i don't think i can install media libraries to convert but i should check this. When you say "media format converter JavaScript libraries", you mean it can convert in front end when users watch the video ?

Comment: roughly...i wasn't sure what you are doing...so you want them to upload, and instantly be able to view?  i'm still leaning towards server-side (again, bc the libraries, imo, are much more fleshed out), you could ajax accept the upload, and spit out the format(s) necessary. and/or there are javascript libraries u can implement on client-side/server-side/FULL-STACK!!!!!.. its really up to your desires. check out http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Open_Source_Video_Processing_Tools_-_MPlayer,_FFMpeg,_AviSynth,_MKVToolnix,_MP4Box FFMpeg is pretty solid. also http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/

Comment: also miro, which i use on desktop http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/ idk how to use it online, but i'm sure there's a way. of note: in the footer: conversion script details: https://develop.participatoryculture.org/index.php/ConversionMatrix  and repo https://github.com/pculture/mirovideoconverter3 lastly some audio iibs on sourceforge http://sourceforge.net/directory/audio-video/sound/conversion/os:windows/freshness:recently-updated/  all the JavaScript ones i'm thinking of are on github/npm. good luck! lmk if you need more, those don't help!